# Why does this javascript function create a deep copy instead of a shallow copy?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is the code and according to a book I'm reading, it states that `arr2` can be a deep copy, meaning new memory is allocated to store the object, which in this case is `arr2`.

```
function copy(arr1, arr2) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; ++i) {
        arr2[i] = arr1[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Well if you pass the same array into both parameters, nothing gets created here at all.

Comment: What is your understanding of "deep" and "shallow copy"?

Comment: technically, you aren't allocating any new memory here at all, since these arrays are allocated somewhere else and passed in as parameters.  This would likely be a "mixed" array, depending on if the elements are primitives or objects.

Answer (score 4):

It's *not* a deep copy. Yes, new memory is allocated for the array itself and its elements, but if objects are part of the array, they are copied as references. New objects are not created.

If it were a deep copy, changing an object stored in `arr1` wouldn't change the corresponding object copied into `arr2`, but it does:

```js
function copy(arr1, arr2) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; ++i) {
    arr2[i] = arr1[i];
  }
}

var arr1 = [1, 2, { 'foo': 'bar' }];
var arr2 = [];

copy(arr1, arr2);

console.dir(arr1);
console.dir(arr2);

arr1[2].foo = 'changed';

console.dir(arr1);    // changed, of course
console.dir(arr2);    // also changed. shallow copy.
```

Comment: Amazing. Thanks a lot man :)

One question though,
When you say they are copied as reference, how is the address of the memory in which the object is stored in passed inside the array?

Comment: "as an object reference" is as far as I can explain it :-) It's how any object assignment, ever, works in Javascript. It's opaque - you can't examine the address or do any operations other than assignment or referencing the object.